# Why did the clones address Palpatine as My Lord?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

I was watching *Revenge of the Sith* the other day and thought it was odd that the clones address Palpatine as My Lord.. I have never seen anyone address Palpatine as My Lord before, it seems odd to address the leader of a democracy as My Lord. Does this mean that the clones knew that Palpatine was Sidious(before the formation of the Empire)??

Comment: The correct 'form of address' for the Supreme Chancellor appears to be "My Lord"

Comment: It was a republic, not a democracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"My Lord" seems to be the official from of address for the Supreme Chancellor.

From *[Attack of the Clones](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Attack-of-the-Clones.html)*

> DAR WAC:
>               The loyalist committee has arrived,
>               my Lord.

Nute Gunway and other Separatist/Confederacy of Independent Systems characters also refer to him as "My Lord," Though it isn't clear if they call him this because he the Supreme Chancellor or because he's a Sith Lord or as a general term of respect.

> NUTE : The invasion is on schedule, My Lord.
>
> GENERAL GRIEVOUS: It will be done, My Lord.
>
> COUNT DOOKU: I bring you good news, my Lord.
>               The war has begun.

Comment: This seems most likely.

Answer (score 1):

Mace Windu called Palpatine that, though I suspect he was being a bit sarcastic.

From [Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0121766/trivia?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu)

> **Mace Windu:** The oppression of the Sith will never return! You, my
>   lord, have lost!
>   **Supreme Chancellor:** [speaking as Darth Sidious]
>   No... no... no! YOU WILL DIE!